# Simplify double square bracket notation when iterating down a list (vector?) in R

Tags: r, list, loops, brackets, square

I want to get air quality information for UK & Eire and have used the fromJSON command in R to access the API available at api.waqi.info.

```
boxStations <- read.csv('ukAqiStations.csv')     # import air quality stations in lat/lon 'box'
boxID <- list(select(boxStations, stationIDX))   # select only the 'stationIDX' column

# now iterate down station IDs in boxID

for (i in 1:length(boxID[[1]][[1]])) {
  waqiAccess <- paste0("http://api.waqi.info/feed/@", boxID[[1]][[1]][i], "/?token=###")
  try(APIreply <- fromJSON(txt = waqiAccess), silent = TRUE)
  ...
}
```

The code works but I want to simplify it, I tried different square bracket arrangements until it worked.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: check this: https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/pluck.html

Comment: Thank you AlexB, I imported purrr and it works:
```> pluck(boxID, 1, 1, 3)    [1] 3160```  gives the same result as ```> boxID[[1]][[1]][3]   
[1] 3160```

I may have to accept that R must use powerful vector notation for this.  I will also look into converting a single csv column import into a simple list.